# Clang tool gives file not recognized error when run using -Xclang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I created a basic clang tool and registered it using FrontendPluginRegistry:

```
static FrontendPluginRegistry::Add<MyActionClass>
    X("my-parser", "my-clang-tool-parser")
```

I am able to successfully run this tool on a source file using the -cc1 option:

```
clang -cc1 -load my-tool.so -plugin my-parser source_file.cpp
```

The above command gives the right result as expected without any issues. Then I ran the tool using Xclang option using the following command:

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang my-tool.so -Xclang -plugin -Xclang my-parser source_file.cpp
```

In this case, first I get all the correct output lines (same as I got with cc1 option), but after the output, I get 2 extra lines:

```
/tmp/test1-856817.o file not recognized: File truncated
clang:error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Though my tool is a part of a huge project, I am guessing the code is correct, since it is able to build successfully and also gives the correct output when run throught both cc1 and Xclang options. It's only the 2 extra lines after output in case of Xclang that I am not able to understand.

I am trying to run the tool using Xclang since I want to pass -I option to include some header files which are in the source_file.cpp, and clang documentation discourages using cc1 for this case.

As far as I know, the tool should give the same output in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: when not using `-cc1` just pass `-fsyntax-only`.

*But why?* `-cc1` is a *very* special flag. To understand we need to look at the compiler clang is impersonating, `gcc`. When you run gcc, it doesn't merely perform a compilation, it may do a number of tasks including compiling. If you run "gcc foo.c -c -o foo.o" then it compiles, yes, but you may also run "gcc foo.c math.f -o program" and then it compiles your C, runs `gfortran` to compile your fortran, runs `collect2` which runs `ld` to link the two produced `.o` files into a single executable. If you run `gcc foo.c` then it will attempt to link it into a program named `a.out`. We call this outermost gcc a "driver" because all it does is run other programs. The program that is part of the GNU Compiler Collection which actually compiles C code is called `cc1`.

Clang follows gcc's design. `clang` is a driver which forks and runs multiple programs. However, there's no `clang-cc1` equivalent, instead it's just `clang` binary again, but where the first flag is the `-cc1` flag. Note that this means that clang behaves as if it were an entirely different binary with entirely different supported flags (and not compatible with the `gcc -cc1` flags I might add). The purpose of `-Xclang` is to tell the clang driver to please pass the following flag along to the `clang -cc1` invocation instead of parsing it as a flag to the clang driver. This is similar in spirit to `-Wl,-linker-flag-here` or `-Wa,-assembler-flag-here`.

You can tell the driver to not assemble or link by passing `-fsyntax-only`. If you want to debug the driver, you can ask it for a dump of what it would run with `-###` as your first flag.